# Universal Windows App (UWP) Not Loading local html file in Webview

Tags: html, windows, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a html contents download from server and its stored in windows storage folder(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path). when I navigate to that page using window.location.href="ms-appdata:///local/inde.html" nothing happens. When I navigate using webView.navigate("ms-appdata:///local/index.html") it shows the page but none of my javascript is getting executed. Anything would be more helpful.

```js
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
        var plugin = new RuntimeComponent.Class;
        plugin.InitializeApp().then(function (response) {
            try{
                (new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(response, "Title")).showAsync()
            }catch(e){

            }
        });
       
    }
};
app.initialize();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should place your html in a subfolder under the local folder. such as `ms-appdata:///local/folder/file.html`.

Comment: @Tao: Yes, I already have my html inside a folder. Just for reference i mentioned as direct file.

Answer (score 1):

> when I navigate to that page using window.location.href="ms-appdata:///local/inde.html" nothing happens.

Problem is that you are using [UWP Web view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx), which is a encapsulated control in UWP that hosts HTML content in an app. Although it uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine to display HTML content in apps compiled for Windows 10, it has its own Apis just for example here for loading content. Not like a traditional browser, you can't use `window.location.href` to redirect the current URL location of the browser.

> When I navigate using webView.navigate("ms-appdata:///local/index.html") it shows the page but none of my javascript is getting executed.

When you want to invoke JavaScript inside the WebView, you will need to call the [InvokeScriptAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx), there are samples for this in the official document I linked above. But if your js code should be executed automatically, there could be many other possibilities which could cause it failed to be executed, please share your html so can we continue to work on this case.

Finally I recommend you to read this blog: [Ten Things You Need to Know About WebView](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/10/18/ten-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview/).

Comment: "index.html" invokes a win runtime component method to get some settings. If I add that index.html inside my package as part of project, it works good. But if i place the same index.thml under "ms-appdata:///local/index.html", My runtime component method is not getting invoked.
Also I added my html and javascript code in my original question above FYR

Comment: @ManojKumar, we discussed a lot about your case, why your html reference cordova?  If it is a standard UWP app, reference to cordova here should not work and WinRT api in your js code should not work in `WebView` control either. For standard UWP, like @ZORRO quoted, "The WebView support for this scheme requires you to place your content in a subfolder under the local or temporary folder.". But we are confusing about the problems I mentioned here, is that possible to share your sample? We're so curious to know how you make it work, many thx!

Comment: @Greg Below is a link of a sample code. I think it will explain you what i m trying to achieve. Basically i want the "ms-appdata:///local/folder/index.html" to access my RunTimeComponent methods.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yiac5sqmokmmw5/CordovaSample.zip?dl=0

Comment: Webview holds a web context while the codes in your application holding a local context. And inside web context. It is not possible to access RunTimeComponent methods. If you are trying to load remote html content that want to access the local context. Please create a [Hosted Web App](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/hosted-web-apps).

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` is a property that used in JavaScript. However `ms-appdata` is the URI scheme used in UWP apps. So `window.location.href` won't work with `ms-appdata:///local/inde.html`. To load local html file in WebView, we should use **[Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate.aspx)** method with a **[Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.aspx)** that uses the **[ms-appdata scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx#ms_appdata)** like what you've done. But here we need note that:

> [Remarks in WebView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx):
>
> To load uncompressed and unencrypted content from your app’s **[LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx)** or **[TemporaryFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder.aspx)** data stores, uuse **[Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate.aspx)** method with a **[Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.aspx)** that uses the **[ms-appdata scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx#ms_appdata)**. The **WebView** support for this scheme **requires** you to **place your content in a subfolder under the local or temporary folder**. This enables navigation to URIs such as ms-appdata:///local/*folder/file.html* and ms-appdata:///temp/*folder/file.html*.

So like @tao's comment said you should place your html and js files in a subfolder under the local folder and then navigate using something like

```
webView.navigate("ms-appdata:///local/folder/index.html");
```